# How to install that .apk which google downloaded but failed to install

Tags: android, operating-system

Sometimes we have less internal memory so when google play finishes downloading it starts installing an app but fails. I make some room for the new app to reside but why I should download once again? I've downloaded the .apk already.

Where we can find that .apk so we can again try to install it?

Answer (score 0):

You can open your rootexplorer using a file Manager and go to `/cache/download` there you will find the .apk file.

The first thing you need to do is "To do this, navigate to Menu -> Settings -> Applications and check the box marked “Unknown Sources“

Once done you can use a file manager like Astro file Manager to install the .apk file

Comment: When I go into root folder it is showing me empty, /cache/ does't has that download folder.

Comment: My device ins't rooted so does it make any difference. Am not finding .apk anywhere.